# Api returning 404 on production

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, next.js, react-fullstack

I have a next.js app and I'm trying to create an api. When I run it as development, the api's get called, but when I run it using `next start` I get a 404 error when calling the api's.

Here's the relevant server.js code:

```
app.prepare().then(() => {
    require('./server/startup/routes')(server);

    server.get('*', (req, res) => {
        return handle(req, res);
    });

    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

    server.listen(PORT, err => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(`> Read on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
    });
});
```

Here's the routes file

```
module.exports = app => {
    app.use('/api/something-cool', cool);
};
```

Cool File:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    ...Code
    res.send({ status: 'ok' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

The api route of `/something-cool` works when I run nodemon, but when I run next run, it returns a 404 error. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a custom server (express) on top of Next.js to customize routes. This means that first, you have to build the Next.js App and then you have to run your `server.js` file in order to serve the App.

**Option 1:**

Builds the production application first

```
next build
```

Then run you `server.js` file:

```
NODE_ENV=production node server.js
```

more info here https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/custom-server-express

**Option 2:**

There is also the option to create the API route within the Next.js App without using a custom server.

See https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/api-routes for more info on how to do it.